# Can I inject string inside v-model value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to update value with v-model and also pass some string with updated value.

Ex. `<input type="range" max="100" value="50" **v-model="mybtnstyle.width '%'**">`

Answer (score -1):

The v-model in Vue is actually combine with a prop call `value` and a event call `input`.

So you can do this by listening to `input` event.

or simply bind the value to style

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <input value="haha" type="text" @input="update" v-model="v" />
    <span :style="{width: `${v}px`}"></span>
   </div>`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      v: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: function() {
      // update your style through input event 
      // or simply bind your value to the style
    }
  }
})
```